# Calling a "main" Java method from Matlab and waiting to finish

Tags: java, matlab, program-entry-point

I have a Java class matlabSMAC that has a "main()" method.

I want to call this method from Matlab. However, whenever I do so, the matlab script continues the execution and does not wait for the main() method to finish the execution.

I have tried to call the method in several ways, unfortunately with the same results

```
matlabSMAC.main(args)
javaMethod('main','matlabSMAC',args)
javaMethodMT('main','matlabSMAC',args)
```

**Question:**
Is there a way to force matlab to wait for the execution of the method to be done before exiting/finishing/continuing the execution of the script?

There is an small comment about this at the end of the following page in the documentation. However, it does not point to any solutions:

https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/invoking-methods-on-java-objects.html

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Matlab does wait for an invoked Java method to finish before continuing.

You may be seeing the effects of that `main` method launching other threads and then returning. (That's the normal design for any Java GUI program.)

What does your `main()` do? You may need the `matlabSMAC` class to provide another method which blocks until all of its worker threads and/or processes have completed.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use the function [waitfor](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitfor.html) in matlab.

`waitfor` stops the execution of matlab script before the object is deleted or closed. But before that you have to create an object refering to your java main function.

Comment: this sounds like a good idea. However it only works with MATLAB objects. Do you know if there is any alternative for custom Java objects?

Comment: Another way to use your method is to make a executable version of your method and call it via [dos(java "yourProgram"]  (https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dos.html?searchHighlight=dos&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) . dos() returns exit status too. You can use the exit status to see whether you want to process forward or not in matlab script.

Comment: Not working either. I have also tried java.lang.runtime.getruntime().exec(...) and then checking for the InputStream until the output is empty.... Unsuccessfully.

I am trying to run this in a computing cluster. Whenever I run this in an interactive session, it works perfectly, however running this in batch mode is what causes the trouble and leaves me here just scratching my head ?.?